# AWS SQS FIFO queue -- Can I have multiple consumers pulling 10 messages at time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs, fifo

AWS sqs FIFO queues are limit the consumer to being able to pull 10 messages at a time.  Can I have multiple consumers all pulling 10 messages at a time to increase the amount of messages I can process at a time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The limit of 10 messages in a single response from SQS is universal to all SQS queue types. However you can definitely have multiple simultaneous consumers each requesting and receiving up to 10 messages at a time.

For FIFO queue consumers, I only see the following restrictions listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-limits.html):

> **Inflight messages per queue**
>
> - For FIFO queues, there can be a maximum of 20,000 inflight messages (received from a queue by a
>     consumer, but not yet deleted from the queue). If you reach this
>     limit, Amazon SQS returns no error messages.
>
> **Message throughput**
>
> - By default, FIFO queues support up to 3,000 messages per second with batching. To request a limit increase, file a support request.
> - FIFO queues support up to 300 messages per second (300 send, receive, or delete operations per second) without batching.

Comment: There's one more, keyed to the Message Group ID.  [Messages that belong to the same message group are always processed one by one, in a strict order relative to the message group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html#FIFO-key-terms) so if all your messages are in one group, only one consumer will have any of them in flight, so that strict ordering is preserved. The other consumers will get no messages in that case.  When the messages in flight are deleted, another consumer (or the same one, it's indeterminate) will receive the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. All queues regardless whether they are standard queues or FIFO queues can have multiple consumers.